# <td>undefined</td> en child rows datatables

Tags: datatables

Tengo una lista de pedidos, que a su vez tienen sub-pedidos. el listado de sub-pedidos, lo estoy haciendo con row child (row details). Funciona bien, el tema es que algunos campos de la tabla me aparecen como *undefined* y en otros aparece el dato correctamente.

He probado la consulta mysql y funciona, la consola de chrome me muestra correctamente el `json` recibido y lo valido en jsonlint.com y es correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es:

```
function format ( d ) {

 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'listar2xxx.php',
    dataType: 'json',

});

return '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" width="100%">'+
    '<tr class="alignRight">'+
        '<td>Etapa</td>'+
        '<td>Folio</td>'+
        '<td>Nombres</td>'+
        '<td>Apellidos</td>'+
        '<td>Estado Pedido</td>'+
        '<td>Estado Lab</td>'+
        '<td>Info Pedido</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr class="alignRight">'+
        '<td>'+d.etapa+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.correlativo+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.nombres+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.apellidos+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.estado_pedido+'</td>'+
        '<td>1</td>'+
        '<td>1</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>'; 
}

$('#listado tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    table = $('#listado').DataTable();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

Cabe señalar que la llamada a child rows la estoy haciendo con `ajax` independiente de los datos que contiene la tabla generada en datatables.

Mi consulta mysql es:

```
<?php
$sql = "
SELECT
etapas.token,
etapas.etapa,
etapas.estado_etapa,
etapas.id,
pedidos.nombres,
pedidos.apellidos,
pedidos.tipo_trat,
pedidos.cliente,
pedidos.correlativo

FROM etapas

INNER JOIN pedidos ON (etapas.token = pedidos.token)

WHERE

pedidos.tipo_trat = 2 and pedidos.cliente = '$id' and etapas.etapa <> 1";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
if (!$resultado){
    die("Error");
}else{
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        $arreglo["data"][]= $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que por más que reviso no encuentro errores en código ni el consola.

**Editado (JSon)**

```
{ "data": [{ "token": "ho381b6zfrdn3c5tb4jd9pve5k8byaq2s7agi8lxa9m5wbu0e", "etapa": "2", "estado_etapa": "A", "id": "4", "nombres": "Hector Mario", "apellidos": "Henriquez Barrios", "tipo_trat": "2", "cliente": "9", "correlativo": "35" }, { "token": "8c5789omesd10zlaxtda3pf8g55ucqrkn2ij9vaycw774bah6", "etapa": "2", "estado_etapa": "A", "id": "6", "nombres": "Sonia", "apellidos": "Gonzalez", "tipo_trat": "2", "cliente": "9", "correlativo": "37" }] }
```

Comment: Pon tambien el json que recibes porfa.

Comment: El ajax dentro de la funcion format no sirve para nada, porque no utilizas lo que devuelve. Y el d.etapa que le pasas a la función format será el que está vacio (de ahí el undefined).

Comment: disculpa @GDP, se me olvido poner el JSON, aqui esta:
{
 "data": [{
  "token": "ho381b6zfrdn3c5tb4jd9pve5k8byaq2s7agi8lxa9m5wbu0e",
  "etapa": "2",
  "estado_etapa": "A",
  "id": "4",
  "nombres": "Hector Mario",
  "apellidos": "Henriquez Barrios",
  "tipo_trat": "2",
  "cliente": "9",
  "correlativo": "35"
 }, {
  "token": "8c5789omesd10zlaxtda3pf8g55ucqrkn2ij9vaycw774bah6",
  "etapa": "2",
  "estado_etapa": "A",
  "id": "6",
  "nombres": "Sonia",
  "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
  "tipo_trat": "2",
  "cliente": "9",
  "correlativo": "37"
 }]
}

Comment: no utilizo el mismo ajax pq son datos diferentes los que utilizo para mostrar informacion. quiza este cometiendo un error en eso.